# Linking Boost Filesystem in XCode 3.2 (MacPorts)

Tags: xcode, macos, boost, macports, boost-filesystem

I am using XCode 3.2 and have installed boost using the MacPorts project (both release and debug) however I am at a loss to get my application to link with boost::filesystem

I have set my library search path to /opt/local/lib but I still get unresolved references when linking the project.

I noticed in another post to add -lboost_system to the "other linker flags" but when I do this I get - libboost_system.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386).

Is MacPorts not installing the right libraries or am I missing something else?

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't indicate what OS version you are build it with. My guess is MacPort defaults to x64 when building and installing ports. [Uninstall](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.uninstall) boost from MacPort then re-install it with universal [variant](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.variants.html#using.variants).

```
%% sudo port uninstall boost
%% sudo port install boost +universal
```

Comment: I had just noticed that variant and am testing it now - was just about to post that I think I found it. Thanks. Will post back soon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the name of the library is not exactly `boost_system` but maybe `boost_system-mt` (the `-mt` is because boost was compiled with thread safety) or even some other suffix.

To be sure, you can look up the name in `/opt/local/lib`:

```
find /opt/local/lib -name "libboost_system*"
```

Comment: I tried all of the variations (-d / -mt / -mt-d ) and they all gave the same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you try the `find` suggested? What was the result?

Comment: I get 8 files: libboost_system-d.a,
libboost_system-d.dylib,
libboost_system-mt-d.a,
libboost_system-mt-d.dylib,
libboost_system-mt.a,
libboost_system-mt.dylib,
libboost_system.a,
libboost_system.dylib,

Comment: Then it's probably because MacPorts indeed built Boost with the wrong architecture. You can either change the architecture for your Xcode project or reinstall Boost by giving MacPorts the appropriate flag (there must be one).